# Article usage: "in context of"

Tags: articles, definite-articles

In a scientific paper,in the sentence  "in context of information theory, we consider the  problem of measuring X " Is an article needed?: "in the/ a (?)  context of the(?)  information theory, we consider "

Comment: The fixed phrase for frame-setting is _In the context of `NP`_. A definite article is required, and as a scientific reader I would count the original example as a typo, and possibly as a mark of a non-native-English-speaker author and/or editor.